# Calculate MouseData/ WheelDelta to scroll one page up

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm able to get the WheelDelta for a line by (120/systeminformation.MouseWheelScrollLines) but is there a way to get the numbers of lines for a page up or down and also the total numbers of lines?

I tried to find another way by changing the Windows settings (Mouse Properies/ One screen at a time) by code but had no luck with it. I played around with pvParam because I can't find the value for WHEEL_PAGESCROLL as MS stated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-mouse-input):

The variable "pulScrollLines" points to an unsigned integer value that receives the suggested number of lines to scroll when the mouse wheel is rotated without modifier keys:

If this number is 0, no scrolling should occur.
If this number is WHEEL_PAGESCROLL, a wheel roll should be interpreted as clicking once in the page down or page up regions of the scroll bar.
If the number of lines to scroll is greater than the number of lines viewable, the scroll operation should also be interpreted as a page down or page up operation.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, int fWinIni);

bool result = SystemParametersInfo(SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines, 0, (IntPtr)0, 0);
```

Comment: Ok, i found the solution for scrolling a page:
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETWHEELSCROLLLINES, (int)WHEEL_PAGESCROLL, (IntPtr)0, 0);

Now i just enter a big value for scrolling to the bottom, maybe "mouseData = 20000".
This is not a good solution because for example in Visual Studio it scrolls not to the end where the End Key is scrolling to, it goes deeper what is not that usable.

Comment: The size of a page depends on the size of the viewport you're scrolling, it's not a system setting.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, do you have a spontaneous idea how i could get to a solution to scroll down to the mentioned line by SendInput in i.e. visual studio?
My goal is to not using the keys because there are a lot of windows or child windows where i can not use keycommands but mouse scrolling works.

Comment: I also tried SetScrollInfo but I think i don't understand it correctly by MS documentation and really a lot of (for me confusing) examples and a few hours of trying.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll a window programmatically? That's a different question.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to scoll. Now i'm trying to do exactly what the Home/ End keys do.

Comment: If the window has a standard scrollbar you can just send `WM_VSCROLL` messages with the appropriate parameters.